# Kubernetes Cronjob runs more than once

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-cronjob

From kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) if I have a Cronjob that is executed each day at 00:00 say, and should only run once, the job template should have these fields:

```
.spec.concurrencyPolicy: Replace
.spec.completions: 1
.spec.parallelism: 1
```

However, the job is  being executed sometimes more than once, but now always, and this cases, the job is not failing either, and it successfully terminates.

Comment: do you have logs that show the job running more than once? can you share them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve some time to read [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including warnings, errors, the job yamls and details to reproduce your scenario will not only help you, but enable you to help others with similar issues!